# Could SE pixel dust be applied to the Careers area?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, user-experience

I made an almost-complete version of [my Careers personal statement](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/edit/84534?verified=False#), hit a navigation button... and then found to my dismay that *without warning* my personal statement that I'd been trying to improve was lost and gone forever as far as electronic means. I was able to write something else and reconstruct some of what I had just typed, but..

When submitting a question on SE, it is hard to accidentally lose what you have typed. There is a warning if you navigate with (at least some kinds of) unsaved content on the page, and if you ignore the warning and (e.g.) close the page, if you come back it is nicely preserved you and you can pick up where you left off. Under MacOS, a slight two-finger swipe to the left and your unsaved work is lost and gone forever.

Furthermore, I realized in tidying up that my positions were out of order, and did a sort of manual bubble sort to get all the new positions dumped at the bottom of the list up to the top. It should be possible to have some default sort order (perhaps by start date, with facilities to *override* the default sort order, and break ties if someone has two positions starting the same month.

SO is designed with heavy UI attention and does the right thing most of the time. In updating my careers page, I met two significant usability defects, which caused me to spend an additional 5 minutes on the update I'd intended:

1. Failure AFAICT to offer any of the usual "protect you from accidentally deleting unsaved work" measures.
2. Sorting order of appearance only available by ten-finger implementation of bubble sort.

*Could the Careers area have a usability / UX audit to make it work like SO in general?*

Comment: I would suggest installing "lazarus browser extension/add-on". Even if they fix it, there's lot's of websites that have this problem. I remember some make you type the whole thing when a validation error happened. The extension saved my life many times.

Comment: I'm sure [JonChan](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/242868/jon-chan?tab=topactivity) who is working on the profile can apply some of his magic dust and fix this up. I'll make sure he knows!

Comment: When writing any more than a sentence or two I tend to either write in a text editor then paste into the form, or write directly into the form then copy the entire text to clipboard before submitting. Saves me from unexpected results that often happen on web forms. SO is one of the few sites where I feel confident in not taking any of these measures. Would be great to see them extend that same protection to all areas of the site as you suggest.

Comment: Darren's hit on the real problem, which is that you can not and thus should not ever rely on such protections on the web, on SO or otherwise (and your problem today is a testament to that). Draft your text in a text editor!!

Comment: The beatings will continue until moral improves.

Comment: Would be a nice standard feature for browsers!

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the feature request! It's long overdue but we've just applied some changes to Developer Story that make sure your changes are saved in local storage prior to submitting them to the server. This means you can navigate away from the page and your changes will be there when you get back to it. This applies when adding/editing new entries on your story or when modifying your personal statement.

It'll be going out to production shortly!