# Editing items in developer story

Tags: bug, status-completed, developer-story

**Steps to reproduce:**

- Go to [own developer story](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/current)
- Click "Edit" for the first position (from the top)

**Current behaviour:**

The fields for "Technologies" and "Responsibilities" get filled with the values of the second item.

**Expected behaviour:**

these fields get filled with the values of the first position.

**Screenshots:**

Before opening edit view:
[image: Before opening edit view]

After opening edit view:
[image: After opening edit view]

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, that's on me, I'm fixing it now

Comment: @DeanWard sorry for bother you, but, can you check my meta-question about add items in the Developer Story, please? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/377346/4092887

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave answered, hope it helps

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Good spot, I missed this when testing. For reference this was related to [this feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303155/could-se-pixel-dust-be-applied-to-the-careers-area) that was addressed yesterday. I've just deployed a fix (maintaining state per item separately rather than based upon the type of the item) and given things a more thorough test run and all seems well. Apologies for the bug :/

Comment: Hey, no problem. Thanks for the quick fix!